# The number of $a$ of the congruence $x^n \equiv a\pmod p$ that make this solvable.

Tags: number-theory

I Proved in this way.

p for odd prime,
$x^n\equiv a\pmod {p}$ is solvable for $a\in {Z_p}^* = \{1,2,\cdots\ p-1\}$

Let $d=gcd\{n,p-1\}$

And $x^n\equiv a\pmod {p}$ is solvable if and only if 
$a^\frac {p-1}{d} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Let r be primitve root of p. Then,
$\frac{p-1}{d} ind_r a \equiv ind_r 1 \equiv p-1 \pmod {p-1}$

Also, $\frac{p-1}d\mid p-1$

So, $\operatorname{ind}_r a \equiv d \pmod d$

$\Rightarrow \operatorname{ind} a \equiv 1\cdot d, 2\cdot d, \cdots \frac{p-1}dd \pmod p$

$\therefore a \equiv r^{1 \cdot d}, r^{2 \cdot d}, \cdots r^{\frac{p-1}dd} \pmod p$ and these are distinct.

Thus the number of a is $\frac{p-1}d$

Is this correct?